# Did (Does?) the Shaolin Wooden Men labyrinth exist?

Tags: history, china, martial-arts

It is mentioned in nearly every fiction on Shaolin Temple, but did it really exist? Wikipedia didn't mention it at all the last time I read, so I assume it's all fiction. But I haven't had a chance to read any serious literature on the Shaolin yet. And if it's purely fiction or legend, maybe you know how the legend started?

[This post here](http://www.bordeglobal.com/foruminv/index.php?showtopic=9850) pretty much sums up the widespread belief (or "claim") about the Shaolin Wooden Men labyrinth.

> To be a Shaolin monk and 
>   learn the secrets of kung fu, you had
>   to pass through a labyrinth filled
>   with skilled warriors, creatures, and
>   traps. At the end, they had to lift a
>   500 or so pound urn out of the way of
>   a door, and while lifting it, their
>   arms were branded with the symbols of
>   twin dragons to symbolize that they
>   had gotten through "initiation".
>
> Once in the labyrinth, there was no
>   way out but to get past the urn. Many
>   died to become bona fide Shaolin
>   monks.

Did such a labyrinth ever exist or is it just fiction?

Comment: I once read a somewhat similar story, but it lacked any mechanical aspects. The wooden men were actually wooden statues in various attack poses. The examinee had to perform the correct block or counter-attack and was graded by some Procter. If he performed well, he passed. If he did poorly he failed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The Chinese LoHan of Kung Fu](http://www.plumpub.com/kaimen/2010/the-chinese-lohan-of-kung-fu/)

> As legend goes the Shaolin Temple has
>   a hall known as the LoHan Palace where
>   **36 wooden figures were set up** [...]
>   These spring loaded dummies would then
>   swing or slide down in the direction
>   of the startled monk with wooden fists
>   or weapons aimed to do damage.
>
> Should the kung fu man be lucky and
>   skillful enough to reach it, **the next
>   phase of the test involved a sloped
>   ramp bordered with twenty-four wooden
>   horses**. The only thing to do was reach
>   the bottom of the slope while dodging
>   these two dozen run away steeds.
>
> **If not historically accurate at least these were the tests devised by
>   novelists writing about the monastery
>   in the Ming Dynasty**. A more
>   reasonable possibility was that the
>   disciple who wanted to return to the
>   outside world and yet retain his
>   connection with the Shaolin community
>   was required to traverse a gauntlet of
>   36 living monks.

The movie [The 36th Chamber of Shaolin](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078243/) and the TV-Series [Kung Fu](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068093/) might have helped in disseminating this "legend".

Comment: So: legend then?